# I want to align search bar to extreme right

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align the search bar in a navigation bar, but all my efforts are going in vain.

I have not included the whole of my navbar code here, only the search bar which is inside my navbar in a div container.

```css
.search {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
    }

    .searchTerm {
      width: 100%;
      border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
      border-right: none;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
      outline: none;
      color: #9DBFAF;
    }

    .searchTerm:focus{
      color: #00B4CC;
    }

    .searchButton {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
      background: #00B4CC;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .wrap{
      width: 30%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .topnav-right {
      float: right;

    }
```

```html
<div class="topnav-right">
      <div class="wrap">
         <div class="search">
            <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
            <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
           </button>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Am I doing it the right way or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Change CSS

```
.wrap{
      width: 30%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0%;
      transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/L7dnvqbm/1/

Comment: or change the left to 80%

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you used ".topnav-right" class and used it to float right. It works well without that too.

```
.wrap{
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

You might need to adjust width and height of the .searchButton class.